# How to use custom font with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox to fill a pdf which contains text form. At one form I have to use a custom font.

I used below code to load a custom font. Even though path is correct It it is failing with the error
`Could not find font: /AlexBrush-Regular`. It fails when it tries to set value at line `f.setValue("Signature")`

```java
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("src/main/resources/static/forms/form.pdf"));
PDType0Font customFont = PDType0Font.load(document, new File("src/main/resources/static/font/AlexBrush-Regular.ttf"));

PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = document.getDocumentCatalog();
PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();

for (PDField field : acroForm.getFields()) {
     if (field instanceof PDField) {
         String fieldName = field.getPartialName();
         if(fieldName.equals("required field")){
            field.setDefaultAppearance("/" + customFont.getName() + " 12 Tf 0 g");
         }else{
            field.setDefaultAppearance("/Helv 12 Tf 0 g");
         }
         field.setValue("Signature");
     }
}
pdAcroForm.flatten();
document.save("filled_form.pdf");
document.close();
```

Comment: Try looking at [Embedding Fonts](https://carbonrider.github.io/pdfbox_tutorial/pdf_embed_font.html).

Comment: This doesn't work in a jar file. You need to do resource loading.

Comment: Please consider telling us at which line you get that error. @Tilman already mentioned the issue that your way of accessing resources won't work after packaging your app as a jar. Additionally i don't see you adding the custom font to the appearance resources or default resources. If you don't tell us more, it is unclear which of the errors is the one causing the error you observe.

Comment: See the `CreateSimpleFormWithEmbeddedFont.java` example on how this is done.

Comment: I tried resource loading it also did not work 
`PDType0Font customFont = PDType0Font.load(pdDocument, ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("static/font/Roboto-Bold.ttf"));`
It fails at this line `field.setValue("Signature");`

Comment: "it fails" is not a useful error description. Btw make sure that if you use resources, that you don't have resource filtering on for ttf files (common newbie error).

Comment: @Vishal, please add the `customFont` to the default resources of `acroForm` and use the name you added it by for constructing the default appearance of the fields.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I have added error in the original post. 
@mkl Can you give me an example. I believe you want me to do something like this
`pdAcroForm.setDefaultAppearance("/" + customFont.getName() +" 12 Tf 0 g");`
I am still getting same error.

Comment: 1) Here's the example: https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/interactive/form/CreateSimpleFormWithEmbeddedFont.java?view=markup  2) you need to include a stack trace instead of "it fails" (how does it fail? What happens or doesn't happen?) 3) "resources" and "default resources" are different things, sorry for the possible confusion. The first is a java thing for files in a .jar (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/60912231/535646), the second means the acroform default resources, see the example. You need to add the font there.

Comment: @Vishal Beware when using the example in Tilman's item 1: There the document is created from scratch while your document is an existing one. Thus, You don't want to unconditionally set the default resources to a clean `PDResources` but instead first try to retrieve the current one. Only if there is no current one, you'll want to create and set a new one.

Comment: Guys it worked. I was not doing resource loading properly that is why I was getting that error. Thanks for the help and sorry for the inconvenience. I should have known better.  I will update the question

Comment: Don't update the question, rather answer it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone for the help. Below code worked for me

```java
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("src/main/resources/static/forms/form.pdf"));
PDAcroForm pdAcroForm = pdDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
final PDResources resources = new PDResources();
pdAcroForm.setDefaultResources(resources);

PDFont formFont = PDType0Font.load(pdDocument,FillPdf.class.getResourceAsStream("static/font/AlexBrush-Regular.ttf"), false);
String fontName = resources.add(formFont).getName();

for (PDField field : acroForm.getFields()) {
     if (field instanceof PDField) {
         String fieldName = field.getPartialName();
         if(fieldName.equals("required field")){
            field.setDefaultAppearance("/" + fontName + " 12 Tf 0 g");
         }else{
            field.setDefaultAppearance("/Helv 12 Tf 0 g");
         }
         field.setValue("Signature");
     }
}
pdAcroForm.flatten();
document.save("filled_form.pdf");
document.close();
```

Comment: Consider the comment of mkl. Existing documents usually have DefaultResources, so it's better to retrieve it and add your extra font. Unless you really want to replace the font in every field.

Answer (score -2):

You can use PDPageContentStream class

```
public PDPageContentStream(PDDocument document, PDPage sourcePage, AppendMode appendContent,
                           boolean compress, boolean resetContext) throws IOException
```

In this code there will be multiple arguments you needs to pass:
Explaination from **JetBrains**

Params:
document – The document the page is part of.

sourcePage – The page to write the contents to.

appendContent – Indicates whether content will be overwritten, appended or prepended. compress – Tell if the content stream should compress the page
contents.

resetContext – Tell if the graphic context should be reset. This is only relevant when the appendContent parameter is set to PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND. You should use this when appending to an existing stream, because the existing stream may have changed graphic properties (e.g. scaling, rotation).

Throws:
IOException – If there is an error writing to the page contents.

And this following way you can set font size and extra properties you wish to style :

```
PDPageContentStream contentStreamMRZ = new PDPageContentStream( test, test, test, test, test );
contentStreamMRZ.setFont( PDType1Font.COURIER_BOLD, 11 );
```

**There are a lot more things you can play with, while doing pdf generations with this class would be more efficient.**

Comment: How exactly does this relate to what the op wants? They want to set the font of a form field and fill that field, not create page content.

Comment: I have just suggested him and the followers who are searching a solution for this, After  seeing those comments i understand those does not work, This would do it in the best way possible.